# How to remove list in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I search to remove List of position when I restart the game

here is my list

```
   List<Positioned> snakePiecesWithNewPoints = List();

    if (score ==0){
          final latestPoint = Positioned(
            child: newSnakePointInGame,
            left: newPointPosition.x * 15.5,
            top: newPointPosition.y * 15.5,
          );
      snakePiecesWithNewPoints.add(latestPoint);
    };


        if (score ==1){


          final latestPoint1 = Positioned(
            child: newSnakeVomiInGame,
            left: newPointPosition2.x * 15.5,
            top: newPointPosition2.y * 15.5,
          );
          snakePiecesWithNewPoints.add(latestPoint1);

        };
```

I tried to remove only latestPoint1 not latestPoint

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? I don't understand what you're trying to fix.

Comment: the game is a simple snake, and when snake catch latestPoint ( good Point), the score increase and a second point is create but it's a bad point. If user touche this bad point score decrease. But when the game restart bad points aren't visible but position are always in the list and when the snake through in one of his position list, the score decrease. So I try to remove previous added point to the list to prevent  bad point ghost. But if I clear all list, it's clear also  the good Point who is the feed for the snake. So I try to remove latestPoint1,2,3,4... but not latestPoint who is feed

Comment: This might be hard to answer without seeing what you use as an indicator as a good point, and a bad point. Because if you're stacking both good points and bad points in one list, you wouldn't be able to find what point you should remove because you can't find the bad point within the list if you don't have an indicator.

Comment: Assuming that these good and bad points are stored in your List<Positioned> snakePiecesWithNewPoints, I suggest that you create your own class, and add a Positioned variable inside that class, as well as an indicator of whether it is a good point or a bad point, and change your implementation of List to use the class you create, so that you can find the bad point within the list you use

Comment: I found an other solution (ugly), at the init of new game I place all bad point out of game limite